# Using 3rd party libraries

Tags: 8, composer

I'm trying to load https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel in a custom module.  I've successfully added the library dependency to the composer.json file and Composer correctly downloads it into the 'vendor' folder.

The PHPExcel library doesn't use namespaces.  How do I access the library?  The following line

`PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($excel_filepath);`

results in

`Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\mymodule\Form\PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found in /home/me/webs/client/myhomedir/modules/custom/mymodule/src/Form/ImportProductsForm.php on line 60`

If possible, I'd prefer not to use the Libraries module.

Comment: This is a plain PHP question about using a class without a namespace inside a namespace. Drupal doesn't change PHP's syntax, so the answer could be given from anybody without Drupal knowledge. It doesn't matter if the error happens with a module code.

Comment: I can see how for someone with extensive Drupal 8 or OO PHP experience, this question might be considered off topic but such people tend to answer more questions than they ask.  For a newbie or a generalist who does not specialize in Drupal, I'm not so sure.

Comment: As general rule, explaining a PHP error/warning is off-topic for us, since Drupal doesn't change PHP syntax. There isn't an explanation of the error that is valid for Drupal but not for plain PHP or other CMSes.

Comment: If your questions are more about PHP than Drupal, they suit better _Stack Overflow_, as the closing reason says.

Comment: I know that now because you've told me but I would have had to have known a lot more about how Drupal 8 works to have known that when I asked the question.  I could never have known that my question was not Drupal specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in your own namespace, that means PHP by default tries to load the class from your current namespace.

To load a non-namespaced class, you need to explicitly refer to the global namespace with a :

```
\PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($excel_filepath);
```

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation & solution Berdir.